# Scala ProcessLogger cant capture output

Tags: scala

why its throwing error on screen instead of capturing in stderr?

```
scala> val stderr = new StringBuilder
stderr: StringBuilder =

scala> val stdout = new StringBuilder
stdout: StringBuilder =

scala> val k = Seq("ls /sdds") ! ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "ls /sdds": error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:100)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:148)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder$$anonfun$runBuffered$1.apply(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:148)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessLogger$$anon$1.buffer(ProcessLogger.scala:99)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.runBuffered(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:148)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:114)
  ... 32 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:340)
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:271)
  at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
  ... 40 more

scala> stderr.toString()
res26: String = ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're seeing isn't captured in the `stderr` StringBuilder because it isn't coming from the launched process. The process isn't executing because the command isn't being parsed correctly.

Try either `"ls /sdds" !` or `Seq("ls", "/sdds") !` and see if that works.

```
val pl = ProcessLogger(stdout append _, stderr append _)
val k = "ls /sdds" ! pl
```

I had to separate the `ProcessLogger` creation from the `ProcessBuilder` but that just might have been the worksheet environment I'm working in.